# Do i have to commit my bitbucket-pipelines.yml each time make a change?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I want to test my pipeline and not have a commit everytime i make a change. Is there a way to prevent this, in order not to have a bunch of unnecessary commits on my develop branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git commit --amend` to push the commit into the previous one, this will trigger the pipeline to run with the new changes without "bloating" your git history with many commits.
Here is a tutorial to help you out: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history